# JPA - How to select rows from a table but the BLOB types lazy?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, blob, fetch, lob

I am using JPA hibernate, wicket, weblogic, and oracle 11.

I have a Table, which has 8 columns, and one of them is a **BLOB** type.
I store big XLS files in this BLOB.
I am querying only 10 rows, but it takes a lot of time, I guess because of the big XLS files. I setted the blob type to be lazy in the entity:

```
@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@Lob
@Column(name = "EXCEL")
private Byte[] xls;
```

But it is as slow as before. How could I really set, to not to load the BLOB files, only if I querying the BLOBs?

Answer (score 1):

[Using Lazy Properties Fetching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties)

> Hibernate3 supports the lazy fetching of individual properties. This
>   optimization technique is also known as fetch groups. Please note that
>   this is mostly a marketing feature; optimizing row reads is much more
>   important than optimization of column reads. However, only loading
>   some properties of a class could be useful in extreme cases. For
>   example, when legacy tables have hundreds of columns and the data
>   model cannot be improved.
>
> Lazy property loading **requires buildtime bytecode instrumentation**. If
>   your persistent classes are not enhanced, Hibernate will ignore lazy
>   property settings and return to immediate fetching.

See [Bytecode Instrumentation for Hibernate Using Maven](http://doginpool.blogspot.com/2012/03/bytecode-instrumentation-for-hibernate.html).